# Arduino and object instantiation in setup()

Tags: c++, arduino, mqtt

I'm really new to C and Arduino, but experienced in high level languages. I tried to find solution in the documentation but could not find anything complex enough to understand the foundations of arduino

So, here the example I'm trying to understand:
https://learn.adafruit.com/mqtt-adafruit-io-and-you/arduino-plus-library-setup

the example is called mqtt_esp8266

the relevant parts:

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include "Adafruit_MQTT.h"
#include "Adafruit_MQTT_Client.h"

#define AIO_USERNAME    "your AIO username"

WiFiClient client;
Adafruit_MQTT_Client mqtt(&client, AIO_SERVER, AIO_SERVERPORT, AIO_USERNAME, AIO_KEY);
Adafruit_MQTT_Publish photocell = Adafruit_MQTT_Publish(&mqtt, AIO_USERNAME "/feeds/photocell");

void setup() {
...
}

void loop() {
...
photocell.publish(something);
}
```

My questions:

- *WiFiClient client;* means that an object is defined or is it instantiated? If it is instantiated, it is instantiated to what?
- *Adafruit_MQTT_Publish photocell = Adafruit_MQTT_Publish(&mqtt, AIO_USERNAME "/feeds/photocell");* here I guess it is using the mqtt client defined previous row. I also guess I cannot use "runtime" informations to declare a topic, since I'm not in the "setup" function, am I right?
- *AIO_USERNAME "/feeds/photocell"* what the hell is this syntax? How do they concatenate strings using spaces?

What I'm trying to achieve is to use runtime information to build the topic. simplifying, I want to publish to AIO_USERNAME "/feeds" + WiFi.macAddress() + "/photocell" but without any fortune. In particular, I do not know how to define the Adafruit_MQTT_Publish in the global scope so that I can use it in both setup() and loop() functions, but instantiate in the setup function so that I can use the WiFi.macAddress() output to prefix the feed name

Comment: FYI, you are using C++, not C. Second, trial-and-error is probably not the best way to learn a language: [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](//stackoverflow.com/q/388242)

Comment: please one question per question

Comment: Special call-out for `#define AIO_USERNAME    "your AIO username"`. It is a macro. It's a leftover from the 1970s, so do your best to avoid them. Anywhere in the code the token `AIO_USERNAME` is found it will be replaced by `"your AIO username"` whether it makes sense to do it or not. As far as macros go, `AIO_USERNAME` isn't bad as it is unlikely to be reused, but in the past people used stuff like `max`, `min`, `l`, and other stuff that often shows up as variable names, functions, or what-have-you. The resulting errors can be very hard to diagnose.

Comment: Have changed the question regarding macro syntax. The problem is not the macro, but the fact the use a space to concatenate 2 strings. Shouldn't be a "+"? BTW, the "+" doesn't work

Comment: [How does concatenation of two string literals work?](//stackoverflow.com/q/12120944) Question is about C, but applicable to C++ also.

Comment: @user4581301 Macros are very common in an embedded environment where there is lots of masking of registers and bit-twiddling. Also, as they are replaced at compile-time, they don't use up precious memory on embedded controllers that sometimes only have 4kB of memory.

Answer (score 0):

```
WiFiClient client;
Adafruit_MQTT_Client mqtt(&client, AIO_SERVER, AIO_SERVERPORT, AIO_USERNAME, AIO_KEY);
Adafruit_MQTT_Publish photocell = Adafruit_MQTT_Publish(&mqtt, AIO_USERNAME "/feeds/photocell");
```

The above three lines instantiate new variables of a global scope. The variable `client` is instantiated using the default constructor of the `WiFiClient` class. `mqtt` is instantiated using a constructor which takes a pointer to client, some server constant etc.

After looking into the code for `Adafruit_MQTT_Publish`: https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_MQTT_Library/blob/master/Adafruit_MQTT.cpp
I see that it is just a convenience wrapper class, that contains a pointer to the `Adafruit_MQTT` object, the `qos` (defaults to `0`) and the `topic`. It implements several different `publish` methods which differ by the type of argument they receive. For example this is the method for `uint32_t`:

```
bool Adafruit_MQTT_Publish::publish(uint32_t i) {
  char payload[11];
  ultoa(i, payload, 10);
  return mqtt->publish(topic, payload, qos);
}
```

You can simply implement the same functionality on your own:

```
WiFiClient client;
Adafruit_MQTT_Client mqtt(&client, AIO_SERVER, AIO_SERVERPORT, AIO_USERNAME, AIO_KEY);
char whatever[] = "What ever";

void loop()
{
  char topic[64]; //Note, if the input can be longer than 64 characters long, change to topic[128] for example...
  strcpy(topic, AIO_USERNAME);
  strcat(topic, whatever);
  char something[] = "asdf";
  mqtt.publish(topic,something,0);
}
```

**As for your question of the syntax**

```
AIO_USERNAME "/feeds/photocell"
```

The preprocessor would turn it into:

```
"your AIO username" "/feeds/photocell"
```

which the compiler then turns into a one long string:

```
"your AIO username/feeds/photocell"
```

This concatenation is only possible for string literals (such as `"string"`). To concatenate stuff at runtime, you'll have to use library functions such as `strcat` and `strcpy`. Please refer to `string.h`: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte

Comment: Ok, let me explain the part I really don't get:

'''
WiFiClient client;
Adafruit_MQTT_Publish photocell;
'''

Why client is instantiated and photocell shall not? Actually that code gives me the error:

error: no matching function for call to 'Adafruit_MQTT_Publish::Adafruit_MQTT_Publish()'
 note: candidates are:
Adafruit_MQTT_Publish::Adafruit_MQTT_Publish(Adafruit_MQTT*, const char*, uint8_t)
candidate expects 3 arguments, 0 provided

So, even your code do not solve the problem that is declare object in global scope but initialize on the setup() function

Comment: @Wishper Yes you're right. There seems to be no 'non-hacky' way to create an instant of `Adafruit_MQTT_Publish` at runtime. But fortunately it's not necessary, since you can implement the same functionality easily on your own. If you really need to create it at runtime, there are some hacks you can do for it, without using heap. You can for example preallocate space for it and use placement new. Or you can make it a static variable. Or you can edit the arduino code on your own and add functionality to change the topic at run time, or simply copy their class and modify the code.